# Symbols in Ruby

Tags: ruby, symbols

I don't know if I understand what a symbol is. I read the following in different places:

- Symbols are immutable, meaning that the content won't change after they are initialized. This means that the object can have many references to it since the content can't change.
- Use Symbols for identity and strings where content matters.
- Symbol object are only instantiated once, and exists as long as the process runs.
- About symbol table

I do not understand these phrases. Last, I don't understand what a symbol object is. Is `:name` a symbol object, or is `:name`just a reference to a symbol object somewhere else?

Answer (score 4):

This quote from the book '[Eloquent Ruby](http://simple-mountain-827.heroku.com/amazon/0321584104/uk)' helped me understand symbols, there's a whole chapter in the book dealing with strings and symbols that is also very good.

> The answer is that we tend to use strings of characters in our code for two rather dif-
> ferent purposes: The first, and most obvious, use for strings is to hold some data that
> we are processing. Read in those Book objects from the database and you will very
> likely have your hands full of string data, things like the title of the book, the author’s
> name, and the actual text.
>
> The second way that we use strings of characters is to represent things in our pro-
> grams, things like wanting to find all of the records in a table. The key thing about
> :all in our Book ActiveRecord example is that ActiveRecord can recognize it when it
> sees it—the code needs to know which records to return, and :all is the flag that says
> it should return every one. The nice thing about using something like :all for this
> kind of “stands for” duty is that it also makes sense to the humans: You are a lot more
> likely to recognize what :all means when you come across it than 0, or -1, or even
> (heaven forbid!) 0x29ef.
>
> These two uses for strings of characters—for regular data processing tasks on the
> one hand and for internal, symbolic, marker-type jobs on the other—make very dif-
> ferent demands on the objects. If you are processing data, you will want to have the
> whole range of string manipulation tools at your fingertips: You might want the first
> ten characters of the title, or you might want to get its length or see whether it matches
> some regular expression. On the other hand, if you are using some characters to stand
> for something in your code, you probably are not very interested in messing with the
> actual characters. Instead, in this second case you just need to know whether this thing
> is the flag that tells you to find all the records or just the first record. Mainly, when
> you want some characters to stand for something, you simply need to know if this is
> the same as that, quickly and reliably.

Comment: Never heard of that book, looks interesting. Thank you for sharing that link!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this IRB session can clear things up a little:

```
irb(main):001:0> "First".object_id
=> 23849064
irb(main):002:0> "First".object_id
=> 23842248
irb(main):003:0> "First".object_id
=> 23835432
irb(main):004:0> "First".object_id
=> 23828616
irb(main):005:0> :First.object_id
=> 301892
irb(main):006:0> :First.object_id
=> 301892
irb(main):007:0> :First.object_id
=> 301892
irb(main):008:0> :First.object_id
=> 301892
irb(main):009:0>
```

Imagine the `object_id` method as being similar to an object's address. As you can see, the "First" string has a different address each time ( meaning a new object gets created each time ), while the symbol doesn't change. Perhaps you could associate symbols with singletons ( as in the singleton pattern, not in a metaprogramming way ), for easier understanding.

Answer (score 2):

You could regard symbols as a sort of constants, but that don't contain an actual value. In languages without symbols you might do something like this for convenience:

```
const BLUE = 1
const GREEN = 2

my_color = GREEN

...


if (my_color == GREEN)
```

In Ruby you can use symbols for this:

```
my_color = :green

...

if my_color == :green
```

It's more efficient since a symbol is just that, a symbol. It doesn't store a value or anything so you don't need to initialize them. I'm not sure how symbols are handled in the Ruby interpreter, but I don't think that's relevant for any novice ruby programmer.

A good guide can be found here: http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm

Answer (score 1):

I think symbols are best explained via use-cases.

For creating constants, they are more expressive than integers.

```
def rgb(color_symbol)
  return nil unless color_symbol.is_a? Symbol
  case color_symbol
  when :red;   { r: 255, g: 0, b: 0 }
  when :green; { r: 0, g: 255, b: 0 }
  when :blue;  { r: 0, g: 0, b: 255 }
  else; { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 }
  end
end

p rgb(color_symbol= :red)
```

Is more readable than

```
def rgb(color_number)
  return nil unless color_number.is_a? Fixnum
  case color_number
  when 1; { r: 255, g: 0, b: 0 }
  when 2; { r: 0, g: 255, b: 0 }
  when 3; { r: 0, g: 0, b: 255 }
  else; { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 }
  end
end

p rgb(color_number= 2)
```

For comparisons in conditional statements, symbols are just compared via their unique address, so they are more efficient than strings, which are compared by length and then every character.

```
def rgb(color_string)
  return nil unless color_string.is_a? String
  case color_string
  when "red";   { r: 255, g: 0, b: 0 }
  when "green"; { r: 0, g: 255, b: 0 }
  when "blue";  { r: 0, g: 0, b: 255 }
  else; { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 }
  end
end

p rgb(color_string= "blue")
```

This is going to be less efficient than using symbols.

Answer (score 0):

This article can be also of interest http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/ as it helped me to understand how symbols differ from strings.

Answer (score 0):

A `Symbol` instance is an ordered set of characters. A `String` instance is a container for characters, a place that can contain any sequence of characters.